# What is the most efficient way to access java methods from c++

Tags: java, c++, performance, java-native-interface

Clearly one could use the java JNI, but would accessing the methods through web services be potentially faster?

The methods that concern me the most are the iterative methods, where *objects* in an array are serially accessed. In C++ the loop is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++)
    get ith object from java // JNI or web service call?
```

Comment: Web services typically have a fair amount of overhead, so it's hard to imagine this working out very well.

Comment: Put the data of the objects in shared memory table and make java and C++ exchange the table index.

Comment: @YSC can you expand on that please - sounds just like what I need

Answer (score 0):

Clearly one *should* use JNI if you're on the same host.  Web services are going to have client/server socket overhead that's not needed in this case.